# Trouble using karate.merge() function

Tags: karate

I'm trying to use the karate.merge() example, verbatim, from the README under the **JSON Transforms** section and it fails with:

```
javascript evaluation failed: karate.merge(foo, { b: 2 }), TypeError: karate.merge is not a function in <eval> at line number 1
```

```
Scenario: merge
    * def foo = { a: 1 }
    * def bar = karate.merge(foo, { b: 2 })
    * match bar == { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

Can anyone help point out what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me. You must be on the wrong version of Karate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/releases

Comment: Ahh... I see the function was added in 0.9.3, I'm using 0.9.2 - time to update :-) Thanks!